# Accessing WSL2 from my LAN (Static IP?)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, windows-11, wsl2

I want to access, from my LAN, services provided by the linux distribution installed into WSL2.

Ok, I know how to remap ports on the host. My problem is that the Windows11 host assigns a different IP address to WSL2 every time I shut it (wsl) down and then start it again, so I cannot establish some kind of permanent rule.
Oddily enough, it also appears not to be a reserved local IP. For example, right now it's `172.21.32.121`.

Is there any solution to such a problem? I mean.. Can I tell windows to assign a static IP to WSL2? The final goal is telling windows that specific services (ports) running on wsl2 have to be always accessible from the LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to remap ports on the host ... [but] the Windows11 host assigns a different IP address to WSL2 every time I [restart WSL] so I cannot establish some kind of permanent rule.
>
> Is there any solution to such a problem?

Quite a few possibilities, actually:

##### WSL1

If your services run under WSL1, then you can convert your distribution (or create a new one) and simply access the services using the Windows host IP.  This used to be the preferred solution for most people, but WSL1 is starting to show its age a bit.

##### SSH reverse tunnels

As you've noticed, the fact that the IP address is dynamic makes port forwarding rules more challenging.  Because of this, one solution is to *reverse* the "source" of the port forwarding so that it originates from *within* WSL2 (which always knows its own IP address).  I go into detail on this in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986).

It does require that you run the `ssh` command each time you restart WSL, but you can do this as part of the same script that brings up your service in the first place.  For instance, place it in `/etc/wsl.conf` in the `[boot]` section as part of the `command =`  string.

##### WSL 1.1.0 or later

While not guaranteed, the [latest WSL2 pre-release](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/1.1.0) that dropped recently includes the following feature in the release notes:

> Attempt to always reuse the same IP address in the WSL NAT network

This means that, in theory, once you assign the port forwarding rules, the IP address would *not change* unless for some strange reason it (or the subnet) was already in use.

As it is currently a pre-release, 1.1.0 has to be downloaded and installed manually through an Admin PowerShell with `Add-AppxPackage <packagename>`, but the WSL team usually releases a production version after squashing any pre-release issues, so keep an eye on the [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) page for a "Latest" with a version number greater than 1.1.0.  When that happens, it should be available in and installable from the normal [Microsoft Store page](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).

##### (Experimental) Bridge Network

> Can I tell Windows to assign a static IP to WSL2?

Probably?  I (still) haven't tried it myself as Microsoft seems to have kept this feature in the "Experimental" category for the last year, but as noted in [the same AU answer from above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986), there is (was?) a feature in WSL2 which allows you to create your own Hyper-V network switch and specify it for use with WSL2.  [This blog post](https://randombytes.substack.com/p/bridged-networking-under-wsl?s=r) remains the best description of the feature I've seen.

There just hasn't been any mention on the part of Microsoft about this feature in the last year or so, so I'm not sure what the plans are for it, or whether it even is still enabled in the latest releases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at
[Accessing a WSL 2 distribution from your local area network (LAN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan).

Comment: Unfortunately, it tells us nothing about how to make WSL's IP static... (or if that's even possible..)

Comment: I faced this problem when I installed xrdp on WSL2 (Debian) and needed to supply an IP address or network name to a Windows rdp client. I have WSL with systemd and installed Avahi to provide a name (which does not change). Need to run `avahi-daemon` at WSL start.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That might be worthy of an answer - I'd be interested in hearing more, at least.  Does that work across the LAN, or just from the Windows host?